# Problem with update sql with excel

Tags: sql-server-2005, excel

I have a problem with this query:

```
UPDATE Provinces 
SET    Provinces.DefaultName=T2.Defaultname 
FROM   Provinces 
INNER JOIN 
    OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
               'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\provinces.xlsx;HDR=YES',
               'SELECT Code, Defaultname FROM [Arkusz1$]') T2 
     On Provinces.Code = t2.Code 
WHERE  Provinces.Code = T2.Code
```

I get error:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>       The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>       Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>       Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

What is the source of this error, and how can I modify the SQL statement?

Comment: is it excel file configured as linked server?

Comment: Sometimes i just do a copy of selected cells into a clipboard and paste into open table using sql server management studio, but you have to have columns in same order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible causes of this detailed here: [Linked Server using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldatabaseengine/thread/83300532-e780-4ac6-9a64-7246e58c253a).

A likely is cause is file system permissions of the temp directory for the sql service login for whoever is accessing that linked server: `C:\Documents and Settings\(sql login name)\Local Settings\Temp`

Answer (score 0):

That is permission denied error. Follow:

[How to import data from Excel to SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686)

[How to use Excel with SQL Server linked servers and distributed queries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306397)

Note If you are using SQL Server 2005, make sure that you have enabled the Ad Hoc Distributed Queries option by using SQL Server Surface Area Configuration.

```
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
```